# How To Plot Stimulus and Response In a Single MATLAB Axes?

Tags: matlab, figure

I want to plot both stimulus curve and response curve in a single figure and signle axes although their scale and unit are different. The following is what I want to get:
[image]

My supervisor has made this figure by an expensive software package called [SigmaPlot](http://www.sigmaplot.com/). The stimulus is in red and the response is in black.

My question is how to make such a plot in MATLAB?

I am aware of a function called plotyy, but it is not helpful.

**EDIT**:plotyy is not helpful because it puts another axes in the right side and it is just unnecessary to add that extra axes.(there might be a way to remove the right axes, do you now how to do that?).

Comment: You can set whatever values you want for the red curve, as long as you put the right label in the end. I.e. plot the black curve, then plot stairs from 0.31 to 0.35, and appropriately place some text.

Comment: "I am aware of a function called plotyy, but it is not helpful."  Wrong.  It would be a fine solution to your problem.  If you care to share **why** it doesn't do what you want, you may get some help.

Comment: @Jonas: Wow...that was very obvious. I don't know why I asked such a simple question(maybe because I am in hurry). If I could, I would delete my question! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to plotting both on the same axes, here's an option making use of `plotyy` and axes properties:

```
t=0:pi/64:2*pi;
figure;
handles = plotyy(t,cos(t),t,ones(size(t)).*t>pi);
set(handles(1),'ylim',[-1.5 1.5],'box','off')
set(handles(2),'ylim',[-18 2],'visible','off')
```

This way you can leave whatever scaling/y offset you have in one plot and not worry about the other one rescaling and messing up your second one.